# Counting entries within time range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database where I am recording how long a user
is active or inactive. If a user switches from active to inactive or
vice versa (or changes any other attribute like address, etc) a new record is added. A simplified version looks like this:

```
UserID       state         state_from         state_to

1            active        2016-12-14        2017-01-15
2            active        2016-12-14        2017-02-02
3            active        2017-01-01        NULL
1            inactive      2017-01-16        2017-03-05
2            inactive      2017-02-02        NULL
1            active        2017-03-06        NULL
```

I would like to count how many users had at some point the state "active", on a monthly basis. The desired output table for January till March would be:

```
date         user_count

2017-01      3    
2017-02      2
2017-03      2
```

For a specific timestamp (e.g. January 2017) I use the following query.

```
SET @stamp = '2017-01';
SELECT @stamp AS date, COUNT(UserID) AS user_count
FROM se_user
WHERE (state LIKE 'active' AND @stamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(state_from,'%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(state_to,'%Y-%m') )
OR (state LIKE 'active' AND DATE_FORMAT(state_from,'%Y-%m') <=  @stamp AND DATE_FORMAT(state_to,'%Y-%m') IS NULL);
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to do it for range of dates (say from January to March). Is there a way to do this?

**Example database and table**

```
-- Set up a test database 
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS se_toy_example;

CREATE DATABASE se_toy_example;

USE se_toy_example;

-- Create example table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS se_user;

CREATE TABLE se_user (
    UserID INT(10),
    state VARCHAR(10),
    state_from DATE,
    state_to DATE
);
-- Populate table
INSERT INTO se_user (UserID,state,state_from,state_to)
VALUES  (1,'active','2016-12-14','2017-01-15'),
        (2,'active','2016-12-14','2017-02-02'),
        (3,'active','2017-01-01',NULL),
        (1,'inactive','2017-01-16','2017-03-05'),
        (2,'inactive','2017-02-02',NULL),
        (1,'active','2017-03-06',NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `calendar_table` to have the month date ranges, with `dt_begin` and `dt_end` for each month.

So your query for the current year become.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/XIAR38230)**

```
SELECT c.dt_begin, count(*)
FROM calendar_table c
JOIN se_user u
  ON c.dt_begin <= COALESCE(u.state_to, curdate() ) 
 AND c.dt_end   >= u.state_from 

WHERE dt_begin >= '2017-01-01'
  AND dt_begin <= '2017-12-01'
  AND state = 'active'
GROUP BY  c.dt_begin   
  ;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTE:** You can use `LEFT JOIN` if want the months with 0 activity.